# Customize multiple mui components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

From MUI's docs you have the ability to customize a component. But is there a way to customize multiple components?
Say I want to customize MuiPaper and MuiList with the same styles.

E.g of customizable components:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiPaper: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to change the default for.
        backgroundColor: '#101010',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to customize the default props. please check below I have added three ways to customize the components. also you can add more components to it.

**theme.js**

```
const mytheme = {
  components: {
    MuiPaper: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ theme }) => ({ // using with theme
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
          color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        }),
      },
    },
    MuiList : {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: { // adding direct CSS properties with screensize condition.
          '@media (min-width:600px)': {
            minHeight: '4.5rem',
            backgroundColor: '#101010',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: { 
        root: ({ ownerState, theme }) => ({ // changing only 'contained' variant or adding new variant.
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
         ...(ownerState.variant === 'contained' && {
            color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
          }),
        }),
      },
    },
  },
};

export default mytheme;
```

**app.js**

```
const App = () => {
  <ThemeProvider theme={createTheme(mytheme)}>
    ...
  </ThemeProvider>
}
export default App;
```